# numpy scipy.optimize.minimize type exception ( after numpy version 1.13.3 -> 1.14.2 )

Tags: numpy, scipy, failed-installation

I'm experiencing a an exception being raised inside scipy since updating from numpy 1.13.3 to 1.14.2

scipy.optimize.minimize call

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(minimization_function, weigths,
                        method="SLSQP",
                        args=(...),
                        constraints=OPTIMIZER_CONSTRAINTS,
                        bounds=(bounds))
```

results in exception being raised:

```
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, 
use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

This is part of of a containerised service using Docker
that uses to install precompiled binaries with.

```
RUN sudo apt-get install python3-scipy python3-pandas python3-numpy
```

Installing scipy or pandas pull numpy 1.14.2

Is there a way to install 1.13.3 using apt-get?

Comment: Yes, it is, however a code-refactoring would be a proper next step.

Comment: Have you tried setting up virtualenvs? You could set one up with an older numpy version, without messing with the global installation..

Comment: @ user3666197  this is not a problem with my specific code. scipy is using the boolean subtract, the `-` operator that is deprecated not may code.

Comment: @ rammelmueller  this is the only solution I see since I do not know of a way to specify version with apt-get

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your `OPTIMIZER_CONSTRAINTS` function returns only numeric values and not boolean.